# Blank HTML SELECT without blank item in dropdown list

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

How implement subj?

when i write:

```
<form>
  <select>
     <option value="0">aaaa</option>
     <option value="1">bbbb</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

then default selected item is "aaaa"

when i write:

```
<form>
  <select>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="0">aaaa</option>
     <option value="1">bbbb</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

then default selected item is blank, but this blank item presents in drop down.

how i can implement SELECT tag with default blank value that hidden in dropdown list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [default select option as blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605516/default-select-option-as-blank)

Answer (score 190):

Just use disabled and/or hidden attributes:

```
<option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
```

- `selected` makes this option the default one.
- `disabled` makes this option unclickable.
- `style='display: none'` makes this option not displayed in older browsers. See: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=hidden) documentation for hidden attribute.
- `hidden` makes this option to don't be displayed in the drop-down list.

Comment: Actually IE 11 does display the "hidden" option.

Comment: Webkit doesn't seem to support the 'hidden' attribute

Comment: As mentioned in [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=hidden), the `hidden` attribute is effectively `display: none`, so to support older browsers: `<option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>`

Answer (score 68):

You can by setting `selectedIndex` to `-1` using `.prop`: http://jsfiddle.net/R9auG/.

For older jQuery versions use `.attr` instead of `.prop`: http://jsfiddle.net/R9auG/71/.

Comment: @IronicMuffin: Thanks; just tested and seems to work on all mainstream browsers in fact.

Comment: @zobidafly: Thanks for editing; I've elaborated a little bit.

Comment: `.attr` will fail in new jQuery versions. Trying to be smart made me fail.

Answer (score 36):

Simply using

```
<option value="" selected disabled>Please select an option...</option>
```

will work anywhere without script and allow you to instruct the user at the same time.

Answer (score 24):

```
<select>
     <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
     <option value="0">aaaa</option>
     <option value="1">bbbb</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: ff/chrome - ok, opera/ie7-9 - not ok

you can test that here (with or without js): http://jsfiddle.net/R9auG/145/


so I recommend js-approach by @pimvdb

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple way to do it using plain JavaScript. This is the vanilla equivalent of the jQuery script posted by pimvdb. You can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8DFSu/1/).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('id_here').selectedIndex = -1;
  }
</script>
```

.

```
<select id="id_here">
  <option>aaaa</option>
  <option>bbbb</option>
</select>
```

Make sure the "id_here" matches in the form and in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. They simply do not work that way. A drop down menu must have one of its options selected at all times.

You could (although I don't recommend it) watch for a *change* event and then use JS to delete the first option if it is blank.

Comment: Why don't you recommend this behavior?

Comment: There are plenty of cases where you want the user to actively pick something from a list. I don't think JS is the most optimal way of doing it (although it seems to be the only way), but i really think there *should* be a way.

Answer (score 3):

For purely html @isherwood has a great solution. For jQuery, give your select drop down an ID then select it with jQuery:

```
<form>
  <select id="myDropDown">
    <option value="0">aaaa</option>
    <option value="1">bbbb</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Then use this jQuery to clear the drop down on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDropDown').val(''); 
});
```

Or put it inside a function by itself:

```
$('#myDropDown').val('');
```

accomplishes what you're looking for and it is easy to put this in functions that may get called on your page if you need to blank out the drop down without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet

```
$("#your-id")[0].selectedIndex = -1
```

It worked for me.

Comment: It would be best to provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ to accompany the answer in order to provide a clearer explanation.

Comment: This assumes the OP is using jQuery.