# Calling function on selected value from drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below html code:

```
<select class="1-100"></select>
```

I am using Jquery to populate the value of above select option:

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $(".1-100");
    for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
});
```

This gives me a drop down with values from 1 to 100. I want to trigger a function when I select a number from this drop down. The function should return the number I selected in the dropdown(displayed on window). How I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML :-

```
<select class="1-100"></select>
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
```

Jquery :-

```
$('select.1-100').on('change',function(){
  alert($(this).val());
  $('#mytext').val($(this).val());
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    var $select = $(".1-100");
    for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
    $('select.1-100').on('change',function(){
      alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="1-100"></select>
```

Comment: This works! But the value which was selected does not appear in the text area after the alert box goes off. Is there are way to see which value was selected from the drop down list?

Comment: @johnmathew...which textarea???? ... plz update your question and show where do you want to print the value..

Comment: @johnmathew Please checkout my answer below.

Comment: I don't want to display it in a separate text area. I want to the selected value to be there in "<select class="1-100"></select>". Right now when I select say "5" , a alert box appears and when I click ok the alert box goes away but the value in the drop down is seen as "1"

Comment: @johnmathew..no i think you are mistaken...just see the demo i have added in my post..if i select value "5" from dropdown then it remains in select as selected value..

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong , Sorry! Now what if I want the select drop down to be empty(with no value)?

Comment: @johnmathew..if you want to empty select then try `$('select.1-100').empty()`

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<label></label>
<select class="1-100"></select>
```

in js

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $(".1-100");
    for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
        $select.append('<option value="'+ i +'">'+ i +'</option>');
    }
     $('select').on('change',function(){
        $('label').text($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: This works fine! The value which was selected does not appear in the text area after the alert box goes off. Is there are way to see which value was selected from the drop down list?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to attach the on `change` handler:

```js
$(function() {
  var $select = $(".1-100");
  for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    $select.append($('<option>').val(i).html(i));
  }
  $select.on('change', function() {
    alert(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="1-100"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using the `change` event on the `<select>` element.

The value of the `<select>` can be fetched using `.val()`.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
$(function(){
  var $select = $(".1-100");
  for (i=1;i<=100;i++){
    $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
  }

  $(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
    $('span').text($(this).val());
    $('textarea').val($(this).val());
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select a value: </label><select class="1-100"></select>
<p>Selected value = <span></span></p>
<textarea></textarea>
```

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://api.jquery.com/val/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: there is no `.text()` for textarea instead use `.val()` as shown in my answer.

Comment: When I add 'select' in the .on() function it the value is seen in "select a value drop down" but if I have a alert statement inside this function, alert does not work!

Comment: Thanks, If I don't want any value to be displayed in "Select a value" , How can I do that?

Comment: @johnmathew If you dont want that text to be displayed, just remove the `label` tags and the text inside it. If you want no option to be shown in the dropdown when the page loads, checkout [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223865/blank-html-select-without-blank-item-in-dropdown-list) (I personally prefer this so that the user doesnt get biased). Please mark my answer as accepted if it has solved your problem and queries.